# Regex PHP IF contains and limit

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, conditional-statements

I have this regex and I'm using PHP preg_match to filter the username.
I want to create conditions:

- Minmal 3 character and must begin with a-zA-Z
- Cannot end with underscore
- if string contains underscore "_" the next underscore should be a-zA-Z0-9 (ex. a_3, hello_w) basically this will prevent username more than one underscore such as a _ _ h. but repeated underscore such as a_h_t_e is not a problem.
- Underscore is optional.
- Username can only contains a-zA-Z0-9 and underscore

This is my code:

> /^(?=.{3})[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*[A-Za-z0-9]$/

I tried a few other ways too. Somehow some valid string are not match.
If someone could help me, please also explain to me what is the diff between ?: and ?=

The string I tried:

- test123
- test_1 (this one is not working with the code above) I tried to put
  {1,} but then some other testing string is not match.
- test_a1
- te_st_12
- h1_h1
- t11
- t11a

Comment: so i can't have my preferd username? why is that ?

Comment: Example your prefered username?
I just want to allow only underscore and some other character.

Comment: what's wrong with allowing anything the user wants?

Comment: to avoid confusions and also avoid unnecessary characters to their username, which is not a good username actually. Thank you

Comment: well you don't me as a user of your site, fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below regex:

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z]((?!__)[a-z\d_])+[a-z\d]$/i', $str)) {
  echo 'matched';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So can you please explain to me what is (?!__) ?
If I want to allow more character such as hyphen, then i Just need to change like this? --> /^[a-z]((?!__)(?!--)[a-z\d_-])+[a-z\d]$/i

Comment: @user3562733 not contains two underscores in the string.

Comment: Hi, If what should I put if I want to limit maximum 20 character?

Comment: @user3562733 Change `+` to `{1,18}`